# Opening the cabinet on a Maytag Centennial Dryer

Tags: repair, dryer

I need to replace the drum support rollers on a Maytag Centennial MGDC700VW0 dryer, but first I just need to get the cabinet open.  Anyone know how to do this?

This dryer has a toe panel, which may provide all the access I will need.  Is that simply held in place with clips?  I can see it has little hooks holding it in place at the bottom.  I tried pulling on it, but I was hesitant to really pull hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will find two screws holding the top on located at the backside of the dryer. With those screws removed the top will come off. With the top removed the front panel retaining screws will be visible. You may have to remove the kick/toe panel to gain access to the lowest front panel screws. I would suggest that the drum drive belt be changed at the same time while it is all apart.

Comment: I plan to add a photo of the back as soon my friend gets back to me.